# Unable to set isdeleted column to 0 for certain values in code column in database

Tags: sql-server

Trying to update a table that has a `varbinary` column. I have a column called code which values need the `isdeleted` column to be set to 0 which so happens to be a `varbinary`. I need to set is deleted to be set to 0 for many values in the code column.

I have tried an `update` statement, setting `isdeleted` to 0 for the code column where the code is in certain values.

```
Update dbo.code
set isdeleted = '0' 
where code in ('1', '2',  '3')
```

Expect these values to be set to 0 however I get an error

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Answer (score 0):

**From Google:** The VARBINARY type is similar to the VARCHAR type, but stores binary byte strings rather than non-binary character strings. M represents the maximum column length in bytes. It contains no character set, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric value of the bytes.

Can you try with-

```
Update dbo.code
set isdeleted = 0 -- Remove single quotes from the Value 
where code in ('1', '2',  '3')
```

I have some additional observation/comments on your requirement. As you mentioned you want to push '0' to your isdeleted column, I guess you are looking for storing 1 or 0 in that column to define a row(may be) is deleted or not. If I guess correct, my suggesting is to use BIT datatype column and store 1 or 0 to that column.

Comment: I get, "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.code' with unique index' The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Whoever designed the database, didn't use the correct data type therefore I am stuck. I thought I could convert in the update statement however it fails. Is there a way to trick it?

Comment: Error explaining the updated value is breaking your unique index conditions. You can check constraints applied in the table and update data accordingly.

Comment: It worked but broke my index. I'll go fix that now. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome @DBA. Please mark the answer accept and give an up vote if it helped :)